# install ipkg on DS413j DSM 5.0

Tags: linux, nas, synology, ipkg

I would like to install sudo with ipkg. First ipkg need to be installed. You can find the bootstrap tutorial of Synology [here](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc#How_to_install_ipkg).

The DS413j has a Marvel Kirkwood mv6282 ARM processor. So I used this file syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh

Then I follow the steps of downloading installing and removing the file. After the successful install I reboot.

I try the command 'ipkg update' with the error ipkg not found.

The opt was not mounted before the installation, I tried the installation again with unmounting it and reinstalling, same error.

Unmount commands:

```
mount
umount /opt
rm -rf /volume1/@optware
rm -rf /usr/lib/ipkg
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Every thing I did:

```
login as: root
root@192.168.1.9's password:


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-05-29 11:35:48 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

MyNas> mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (defaults)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (gid=4,mode=620)
/sys on /sys type sysfs (0)
/tmp on /tmp type tmpfs (0)
/proc/bus/usb on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (0)
/dev/vg1/volume_1 on /volume1 type ext4 (usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,synoacl)
MyNas> umount /opt
umount: can't umount /opt: Invalid argument
MyNas> rm -rf /volume1/@optware
MyNas> rm -rf /usr/lib/ipkg
MyNas> cd /volume1/@tmp
MyNas> wget http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstabl
e/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
--2014-10-23 17:05:41--  http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
Resolving ipkg.nslu2-linux.org... 140.211.169.161
Connecting to ipkg.nslu2-linux.org|140.211.169.161|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 252947 (247K) [text/plain]
Saving to: 'syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh'

100%[======================================>] 252,947      218KB/s   in 1.1s

2014-10-23 17:05:43 (218 KB/s) - 'syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh' saved [252947/252947]

MyNas> sh syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
Optware Bootstrap for syno-mvkw.
Extracting archive... please wait
bootstrap/
bootstrap/bootstrap.sh
bootstrap/ipkg-opt.ipk
bootstrap/ipkg.sh
1232+1 records in
1232+1 records out
bootstrap/optware-bootstrap.ipk
bootstrap/wget.ipk
Error: CPU not Marvell Kirkwood, probably wrong bootstrap.xsh


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-05-29 11:35:48 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

MyNas> wget http://web.archive.org/web/20121005035819/http://wizjos.endofintern
et.net/synology/archief/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh
--2014-10-23 17:06:23--  http://web.archive.org/web/20121005035819/http://wizjos.endofinternet.net/synology/archief/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh
Resolving web.archive.org... 207.241.226.190
Connecting to web.archive.org|207.241.226.190|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 251866 (246K) [text/plain]
Saving to: 'syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh'

100%[======================================>] 251,866      239KB/s   in 1.0s

2014-10-23 17:06:25 (239 KB/s) - 'syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh' saved [251866/251866]

MyNas> sh syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm-ds111.xsh
Optware Bootstrap for syno-mvkw.
Extracting archive... please wait
bootstrap/
bootstrap/optware-bootstrap.ipk
bootstrap/wget.ipk
1227+1 records in
1227+1 records out
bootstrap/bootstrap.sh
bootstrap/ipkg.sh
bootstrap/ipkg-opt.ipk
Creating temporary ipkg repository...
Installing optware-bootstrap package...
Unpacking optware-bootstrap.ipk...Done.
Configuring optware-bootstrap.ipk...Done.
Installing ipkg...
Unpacking ipkg-opt.ipk...Done.
Configuring ipkg-opt.ipk...WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/syno/ssl/openssl.cnf
Done.
Removing temporary ipkg repository...
Installing wget...
Installing wget (1.12-2) to root...
Configuring wget
Successfully terminated.
Creating /opt/etc/ipkg/cross-feed.conf...
Setup complete.


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-05-29 11:35:48 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

MyNas> reboot
MyNas>
Broadcast message from root@MyNas
        (/dev/pts/1) at 17:07 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!

login as: root
root@192.168.1.9's password:


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2014-05-29 11:35:48 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

MyNas> ipkg update
-ash: ipkg: not found
MyNas>
MyNas> mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (defaults)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (gid=4,mode=620)
/sys on /sys type sysfs (0)
/tmp on /tmp type tmpfs (0)
/proc/bus/usb on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (0)
/dev/vg1/volume_1 on /volume1 type ext4 (usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,synoacl)
/volume1/@optware on /opt type bind (bind)
MyNas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the logs above ipkg was installed succesfully.
you can check the version like this:

```
/opt/bin/ipkg -v
```

the ipkg update command didn't work because of the wrong location set in the .profile to the ipkg service.

If I go to the right location and then try to run the update, it works fine.

```
cd /opt/bin
./ipkg update
```

You can find more information in this topic if you are still having any trouble.
http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=91861&p=346607#p346607